# Firebase: Is there any way to add phone number to a google signed in user in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I have implemented the google sign in my flutter app using firebase auth. I want to add a phone number to the user who is already signed in in the app using google. I have tried the phone authentication. It  created another and replaces the existing user from the app. Is there any ways to integrate both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set a phone number for a Firebase Authentication user from the client-side SDKs without verifying it.

But from a trusted environment (such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions), you can use one of the Admin SDKs to do this. The the documentation on [updating a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) for an example. You'd have to wrap this functionality in a custom API and call that from your Flutter app.

Alternatively, you can store the phone number (and other information) for a user in a cloud database, such as Cloud Firestore or Firebase Realtime Database. This is actually the most common way to store additional information about a user profile, as this way you can also query this information from the application.